Having trouble with element positioning
I don't quite understand what's going wrong with my CSS. I'm new to CSS but I'm trying to center a H1 in the header and it's being pushed out of the div by the img or im doing something horribly wrong
CSS:
header{
background-color: #E5AF42;
height: 150px;
margin: 0;
}
header img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 25px 0 25px 25px;
}
header h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; 
    margin: 0;
}

html:
    <header>
        <a href="index.html" class="flex">
            <img src="images/dog.png" alt="outline of a dog's face with heart above it">
            <h1>Delilah's Doggy Daycare</h1>
        </a>
    </header>


I've tried lowering the margin and even removing it on the img and while that did change it, it didn't quite have the expected result. Like I stated before I'm trying to align it in the center of the header not below it.


You have a fixed header height
for the below code

justify-content: center; 
align-items: center;

you can move it to the <a> element
check the code below
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      header {
        background-color: #e5af42;
        margin: 0;
      }
      header a {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      header img {
        margin: 25px 0 25px 25px;
        padding: 0 20px;
      }
      header h1 {
        font-size: 48px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="index.html">
        <img
          src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20220620/ourmid/pngtree-pink-cute-cat-icon-animal-png-yuri-png-image_5230763.png"
          alt="outline of a dog's face with heart above it"
          height="100"
          width="100"
        />
        <h1>Delilah's Doggy Daycare</h1>
      </a>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>



